# How to find a key-value pair in multilevel Object?

Tags: javascript, key-value

I'm using this data structure in my `Angular` project. I'm not sure Angular it does matter, but maybe it has benefits:

```
const content = [
    {
        "id": 1, // language id
        "name": "english",
        "code": "en",
        "menus": [
            {
                "id": 1, // group id
                "lang_id": 1,
                "name": "Default",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "id": 2, // item id
                        "name": "About us",
                        "menu_id": 1,
                        "is_hidden": 0,
                        // ...
                    },
                ],
            },
            // ...
        ],
    },
    // ...
]
```

I know the `id` of the language, the group and the item too with these variable names:

```
private lang_id = 1;
private group_id = 1;
private item_id = 2;
```

In the data structure I have many "languages" with many "groups", and I have many "items" in the "groups".

I tried to use this code, but I think here need to be a better soultion:

```
let indexLang: number;
let indexGroup: number;

for (let i = 0; i < this.content.length; i++) {
  if ( this.content[i].id === this.lang_id) {
    indexLang = i;
    break;
  }
}
for (let i = 0; i < this.content[indexLang].menus.length; i++) {
  if ( this.content[indexLang].menus[i].id === this.group_id) {
    indexGroup = i;
    break;
  }
}
// and another for loop to find the item...
```

Is there a better way to find the `is_hidden` key-value pair with the least resources?

Comment: Have you tried something? Surely the questions about how to iterate through arrays and match objects by a certain property are there in abundance... You should have a go at it.

Comment: what you meant with `find the right is_hidden key-value pair` ?

Comment: I just updated the codes.

Comment: FYI there is no JSON in the given code, it is a JavaScript Object that is assigned to a variable `content`. JSON is a textual representation of data. In javascript JSON is of the type `string` and has to be parse before you can work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```js
const content = [
    {
        "id": 1, // language id
        "name": "english",
        "code": "en",
        "menus": [
            {
                "id": 1, // group id
                "lang_id": 1,
                "name": "Default",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "id": 2, // item id
                        "name": "About us",
                        "menu_id": 1,
                        "is_hidden": 0,
                        // ...
                    },
                ],
            },
            // ...
        ],
    },
    // ...
]

let lang_id = 1;
let group_id = 1;
let item_id = 2;

let language = content.find(item => item.id === lang_id);
let group = language.menus.find(item => item.id === group_id);
let item = group.items.find(item => item.id === item_id);

console.dir(item)
```

You for sure need to add some error handling for the case that one of the ids does not exists. And you could chain those finds:

```
try {
  let item = content.find(item => item.id === lang_id)
               .menus.find(item => item.id === group_id)
               .items.find(item => item.id === item_id);
} catch( err ) {
   // one of the ids did not exists
}
```

Comment: In this case the created `item` object is linked to the original `content` variable? I mean if I do `item.is_hidden = 0;` it will be updated on the `content[0].menus[0].items[0].is_hidden` key too?

Comment: @netdjw yes in both cases, `item` referrers to the nested object.